# Remove common object from js array and create new js array

Tags: javascript, json

I have this below JSON array. In this, I want to find the common item object and add it to another list and remove that from the source list.
The item with id is common for two objects. Also, the list is dynamic.

```
 [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "item": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "itemA"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "item": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "itemA"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "item": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "itemB"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Please attempt to write your own code. If you are having problems, we will look at your code and assist.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag. This is not really a question about JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` in combination with a `Map` for keying your data:

```js
const data = [ { "id": 1, "item": { "id": 1, "name": "itemA" } }, { "id": 2, "item": { "id": 1, "name": "itemA" } }, { "id": 3, "item": { "id": 2, "name": "itemB" } }  ];

const [map, dupes] = data.reduce(([map, dupes], obj) =>
    map.has(obj.item.id) ? [map, dupes.concat(obj)] : [map.set(obj.item.id, obj), dupes]
, [new Map, []]);

const uniques = [...map.values()];

console.log(uniques);
console.log('dupes:');
console.log(dupes);
```

After reading your comments, it seems you want to reject anything that has a duplicate, so not even keeping one original. So then the code could be:

```js
const data = [ { "id": 1, "item": { "id": 1, "name": "itemA" } }, { "id": 2, "item": { "id": 1, "name": "itemA" } }, { "id": 3, "item": { "id": 2, "name": "itemB" } }  ];

const map = new Map(data.map(obj => [obj.item.id, []]));
data.forEach(obj => map.get(obj.item.id).push(obj));
const uniques = [].concat(...[...map.values()].filter(arr => arr.length === 1));
const dupes = [].concat(...[...map.values()].filter(arr => arr.length > 1));

console.log(uniques);
console.log('dupes:');
console.log(dupes);
```

Comment: i want duplicates list, and is it js??

Comment: The duplicates list is called `dupes` in this code. Yes, this is JS. You can press "Run code snippet" to see it run. If you want some clarification, just let me know which part you want clarified.

Comment: The above code has 2 duplicates. but the result has 1 duplicate

Comment: Does this comes in plain js??

Comment: This is plain JS. Did you run it? Is there an issue?

Comment: About the number of duplicates: As I understood, when you have twice id 1, then the *second* one is a duplicate of the first. So then there is one duplicate. Do you want the first one to also be called a duplicate?

Comment: OK, I see no more response, so I just added a second version of the code to my answer. That one will produce a list with 2 duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

- [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over your Array, passing an accumulator.
- Accumulator keeps track of found elements.
- Check accumulator if iterated element was previously found by `id`, if yes push it into duplicates.
- Otherwise push it into `arr`.

```js
const arr =  [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "itemA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "itemA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "itemB"
    }
  }
]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
  if (acc.found[el.item.id]) {
    acc.duplicates.push(el)
  } else {
    acc.source.push(el)
  }
  
  acc.found[el.item.id] = true
  
  if (i === arr.length - 1) 
   delete acc.found
  
  return acc
}, {
  source: [],
  duplicates: [],
  found: {}
})

console.log(result.source) // source with removed duplicates
console.log(result.duplicates) // array of duplicates
```